# Como converte ng-repeat do angular para Flask?

Tags: angularjs, flask

Como posso fazer a mesma função do ng-repeat do Angular em Flask?

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in oCtrl.ListaProdutosAno | filter:{codigoProduto: produto_estatistica.codigoProduto} track by x.codigoProduto + x.ano">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 4%">
            {{x.ano}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Sei que a parte `ng-repeat="x in oCtrl.ListaProdutosAno` pode ser feito com um `for x in oCtrl.ListaProdutosAno`, mas não entendi muito bem o que a parte `| filter:{codigoProduto: produto_estatistica.codigoProduto} track by x.codigoProduto + x.ano` faz e como poderia ser no Flask.

Comment: Talvez não seria o caso de já trazer o `list` formatado? Porque no caso do `ng-repeat` imagino que é feito no lado do cliente, e o `flask` utiliza o template engine processado do lado do servidor. Não seria o caso de refatorar a lógica do retorno dos produtos?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não tinha pensado nisso, vlw pela dica.